# System said I earned "view close votes" privilege, but my profile doesn't show that, is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In my Achivements tab, I was told I had earned the close votes privilege:

[image]

But in my profile, I haven't.

Which one is correct?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Most important thing to keep in mind is this:  Once you get a privilege at a certain reputation level, ***it is possible to lose the privilege if you drop below that reputation level***.  This happens more often than you would think, unfortunately, so it's not uncommon to see this happen.

---

You currently have 243 reputation points.  You need 250 to get the privilege you specified, which is why you don't see the priv.  (This is not, however, a bug.)

Also keep in mind that the notifications box doesn't realtime revoke messages (I still have messages from when the global SE wide issue with the Marshall badge gave me three of them, heh).

It is possible for an upvote to have been given for an answer, but then removed by someone or because a user was removed from the system and their upvote was undone because of that).

I do not have in-depth access to see your reputation, but check your "reputation" tab to see if there are any -10s on there.

Comment: No -10's for the past 30 days.

Comment: @CollDue96 It may have been someone upvoted but then immediately retracted (accidental click).  In either case, your reputation is 243 according to the system, so you *had* 250, but if your rep. drops you lose those privs.  Which may have been the case here

Comment: I don't care now because I just got a real +10 so now I have the privilege. :)

Comment: @CollDue96 One of your answers was converted to a comment, that put you below 250.

Comment: @Seth thanks for checking that, I don't have in-depth tools to do that :)  (He got an upvote though, so oorah!)

Comment: @Seth thanks for that